# How can I open a json file from another folder?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to make a code in **python** that imports a JSON file from a folder into my program in order for it to access the data inside. However, I am facing errors

```
    global bees
    with open('data/bees.json') as f:
        bees = json.load(f)["bees"]
```

Where in the *data/bees.json* I have this:

```
    {
    "bees": []
    }
```

The error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Entertainment/Coding/Python/Pygame/BUG WORLD/main.py", line 70, in <module>
    bees = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\ernes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ernes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\ernes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\ernes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Is there a way I am able to import JSON files from another folder without causing any errors?? Please help

Comment: Just write the path in `open('/path/to/file/bees.json')`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: The file is clearly found. Otherwise you would get a `FileNotFoundError`. Maybe your JSON is invalid. There could be a `\0`-byte at the beginning of the file or something. Delete everything in front of the first `{`.

Comment: You can do a `print(repr(f.read()))` to see what is really in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're on Windows, so:

```py
with open(r'c:\path\to\file\bees.json') as json_file:
    bees_js = json.load(json_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The relative path should be open("data/bees.json") without the `/`, starting a path with `/` means absolute path from the root.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the following:

```
import json

with open('path_to_file/bees.json') as json_file:
    bees_js = json.load(json_file)
```